# Simple Tweak to Javascript for button in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can we change the following code to work when the button is clicked.  As of right now it's configured to a submit button, which the button is not.

Button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="login()">Log in</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
 dpd.users.me(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    location.href = "/";
  }
  });
 $('form').submit(function() {
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  dpd.users.login({username: username, password: password},  function(session, error) {
    if (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    } else {
      location.href = "/welcome.html";
    }
  });
  return false;
 });
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.showLogin = function(val) {
$scope.loginVisible = val;
if (val) {
  $scope.username = '';
  $scope.password = '';
  }
 };

 $scope.login = function() {
dpd.users.login({
  username: $scope.username,
  password: $scope.password
  }, function(session, error) {
  if (error) {
    alert(error.message);
    } else {
    $scope.showLogin(false);
    getMe();

    $scope.$apply();
  }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form ng-submit="login()"><!-- /* input items */ --></form>
```

Use [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) for submit buttons. Avoid using jQuery, and define a $scope.login function in your controller

Comment: Thanks for the response!  What would I add to my button to make it work?  Here is what I have... <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />  and I added my controller to the post above.  Thanks so much again

Comment: `input type="submit"` on the button is what you need to make it work - so you're good!

Comment: this has other advantages like working well with html5's `required` attributes for non-optional input fields (it checks for those inputs to be filled out before executing $scope.login() )

Answer (score 3):

In order to run the code that currently exists within the 'form.submit' function, you'll need to change the jQuery selector and event it is tied to, or wrap the login info in a form, and change your button to a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Log In" />
```

If you don't want to wrap the login data in a form, change the jQuery as follows:

```
$('form').submit(function() { // this should change to the following
$('button.btn-primary').on('click', function() {
```

you may also consider giving your button an ID:

```
<button id="login_button" class="btn btn-primary>Log in</button>
```

And then you can use the ID as your jQuery selector:

```
$('#login_button').on('click', function() {
```

for more info about the 'on' event handler: https://api.jquery.com/on/